# Extract variable name from formula and use it to get column from list

Tags: r

I have a formula object (from a linear regression model) which is something like this: `lpsa ~ x1 + x2`
I then use the model to predict some values and now I want to retrieve the correct values from the dataset to calculate the MSE, in this case this is done with:

```
pred <- predict(model,data)
values <- data$lpsa 
.... # calculate mse
```

Now I don't want to hardcode the lpsa in my function and I tried to use:

```
columname <- formula(model)[[2]] # x == lpsa
valrues <- data$columname
```

but it returns NULL. `typeof(x)` is `"symbol"` but i haven't found any helping resources.

Comment: It would help to have a reproducible example.

Comment: 1st load the package ElemStatLearn, then import the data with `data("prostate")` and save it in and use a model, e.g. `lm(lpsa~ .,data=data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to convert it to a string

```
data[[toString(formula(model)[[2]])]]
```

Also, look at `terms(model)`

Comment: thanks - this `data[[string]]` was the missing link.